# How prevent ember-data send request to server?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I've a route which user can pick more options for your account. But when I enter on this route, ember send a GET to my API. How I avoid this since I've the information I need.

I'm using Ember JS 2x.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    searchPlaces: Ember.inject.service(),
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    },
    afterModel(model) {
        let token = model.get('token');
        let places = model.get('places');

        this.set('places', places);
        this.set('token', token);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you post your js for the route in question, it would be easier to see why the request is being made.

Comment: @sheriffderek I'll post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I recommend reading the [`DS.Store` API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html). There are four methods that seem relevant:

- [`findRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord) -- returns a Promise, tries memory first, then an API call
- [`findAll`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll) -- like `findRecord`, but for all records of a type
- [`peekRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekRecord) -- returns the record if it's in memory already, or `null` if not; doesn't make an API call
- [`peekAll`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekAll) -- returns an `Array` of the records of a type that are already in memory

I suspect you want to call `store.peekRecord` or `store.peekAll` in your route if you want to avoid the API lookup.

Comment: This is the correct anwser i change `findAll` for `peekRecord` and work well. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that Ember Data has other cases that can trigger network requests for your data, e.g. when resolving async relationships that haven't yet been loaded, or when it decides to reload your record in background to keep it fresh. All of them go through the corresponding adapter method and, eventually, the `ajax` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you access some relationships of that account in "some route" template it might need to lazy-load them and that's why GET request could fire.

If you want to get rid of that request you could override `model` of `some route` and make sure you don't use `store.find` there.